# Power series of Isometries

Tags: linear-algebra, power-series, isometry

I was asked to show, given an isometry U from a finite dimensional inner product space V to itself that
$$
A_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{0}^{n}U^{n}(x) \to 0 \text{ as } n\to \infty
\text{ for} x\in Im(I-U) 
$$
so letting $ y-U(y)$
$$
A_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{0}^{n}U^{n}(y-U(y))=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{0}^{n}U^{n}(y)-U^{n+1}(y)=\frac{U(y)-U^{n+1}(y)}{n}
$$
and so clearly for a central isometry
$$
|A_n|\leq \frac{|U(y|+|U^{n+1}(y)|}{n}=\frac{2|U(y)|}{n}\to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty
$$
as required

For a general isometry $U(x)=Ax+v$ things are less straightforward,
in fact it seems to me that taking $U:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ s.t $U(x)=x+v$,  say, then
$$
A_n(-v)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{0}^{n}U^{n}(0-U(0))=\frac{U(0)-U^{n+1}(0)}{n}=\frac{-v-nv}{n}\to -1 \text{ as } n \to \infty
$$
Have I messed up somewhere with my counter-example or is the result indeed only true for central isometries?

Comment: Lacking any context, I would assume that "isometry of an inner product space" means a _linear_ isometry, rather than an _affine_ isometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  I would add that usually when people refer to "isometries" of inner product spaces (or more generally, of normed vector spaces), they mean only *linear* maps which are isometries, not arbitrary maps.  To refer to possibly non-linear isometries, you usually say something like "affine isometries".

Comment: Ahh ok, thank you very much.